# AlarmManager/BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've been trying to setup my first alarm using AlarmManager and BroadCastReceiver as explained here: http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html

My setup:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="es.radiopodcastellano.player.SleepAlarm" />
```

My main Activity onCreate (this code actually resides on a subclass, but to simplify I put it there):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // <Stripped code>
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) currentContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), SleepAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000)),pendingIntent);
}
```

SleepAlarm.java:

```
public class SleepAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("RPod_SleepAlarm","Alarm!!");
}

}
```

Output from "adb shell dumpsys alarm" show this, so it seems the intent is being called:

```
  es.radiopodcastellano.player
221ms running, 32 wakeups
44 alarms: flg=0x4 cmp=es.radiopodcastellano.player/.SleepAlarm
```

However, Logcat shows nothing for "RPod_SleepAlarm" tag. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The receiver on the manifest was inside another receiver for a widget, and it must be a children of the application. So, if you're having the same behaviour as me, please check that you've set up the AndroidManifest.xml correctly:

Comment: Perfect answer! How stupid I was! This was the silliest thing ever done in hurry, because I knew how it works! Damn!